# How to generate unit tests from a JS module automatically?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, yeoman, intern

I have inherited a project with multiple JavaScript files. Each of them has a bunch of functions; the files are defined in AMD style.

For instance:

`math.js`

```
define([], function () {

  return {

    func1: function (a, b) { 
      return a + b;
    },

    func2: function (c, d) {
      return c + d;
    },

  };
});
```

I would like to generate a new file in the `tests` folder with the name (`math.js`) that will contain the boilerplate code for the unit tests in `tdd` style for the [`intern`](https://theintern.github.io/) framework.

I have used the [`intern-generator`](https://github.com/naglalakk/generator-intern), a Yeoman generator that will do scaffolding and generate a test file with a specified name and path, however, this one won't let me create unit tests that refer to the functions from the JS file.

So, for the `math.js` source file, I'd like to create a test file (automatically):

```
define(function (require) {
  var tdd = require('intern!tdd');
  var assert = require('intern/chai!assert');
  var math = require('src/app/math');

  tdd.suite('Suite name', function () {

    tdd.test1('Test foo', function () {
      math.func1('breaks');
    });

    tdd.test('Test bar', function () {
      math.func2('breaks');

    });
  });
});
```

This way, I can start with all unit tests files pre-created and I know that all my unit tests will initially break and I will make them pass one by one. Also, this way I can be sure that I got all functions from my source script files into tests.

Naturally, I would like to generate those tests .js files for all my source .js files. Is there any generator or a library/script that will let me do this?